# Complex Regex (line breaks, multiple variables)

Tags: regex, powershell

I have an issue where I need to identify this pattern:

```
"series":[{
"name":"Some variable thing",
"data":[,,,]}
```

There are line breaks that I'm concerned with, "Some variable thing" will be of arbitrary length, and the number of commas in the "data" brackets will be variable.

I could figure this out with a few hours of effort maybe, but maybe somebody here can give me a kick start.

**Edit**

Here is a truncated sample of the HTML file that is produced:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html><body><div class="main-section"></div><script>var options = {
"chart":{
"id":"ChartID-qn5g8ay9",
"height":"350px",
"type":"bar",
"stacked":true},
"title":{
"text":"Fictional Books Sales"},
"legend":{
"show":true,
"position":"top"},
"plotOptions":{
"bar":{
"horizontal":true}},
"dataLabels":{
"enabled":true,
"offsetX":-6,
"style":{
"fontSize":"12px"}},
"series":[{
"name":"Tank Picture",
"data":[,,,,,,]},{
"name":"Bucket Slope",
"data":[53,32,33,52,13,43,32]}],
"xaxis":{
"categories":["2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014"]}}
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#ChartID-qn5g8ay9'),
            options
        );
chart.render();
```

Note that there will be a variable number of charts contained in the file, but I am only concerned with replacing the first instance of `"data":[,,,,,,]},{` that follows each instance of `"series":[{` with `"data":[0,,,,,,]},{`, where the number of array members (commas) is variable.

Comment: is this JSON data? If so, no need for regex. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Well... it's JavaScript that's written to an HTML file using a project called PSWriteHTML, the project doesn't currently suppress zeroes in the output, so I'm doing a find/replace on the output file until the devs get around to fixing this bug... if they do.  https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteHTML/discussions/282#discussioncomment-1548839

Comment: So, maybe it's JSON?  But if so I'd have to extract it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the *mix* of data formats in your input (HTML, JavaScript, JSON), which makes extraction and selective modification of the embedded JSON data a challenge, a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) solution is indeed probably simplest:

Use the regex-based [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator):

```
(Get-Content -Raw file.htm) -replace `
  '(?<="series"\s*:\s*\[\{\s*"name"\s*:\s*"[^"]+",\s*"data":\s*\[),',
  '0,'
```

- [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) `-Raw` reads the input file as a whole, as a single, multi-line string, which enables matching across lines.
- A positive lookbehind assertion (`(?<=...)`) is used to match the text preceding the `,` of interest; the latter is then replaced with `0,`
- For robustness, `\s*` is inserted to match varying amounts of whitespace, if any, in places where they have no syntactic meaning in the JSON string, to guard against incidental formatting variations.

To experiment with the regex interactively, see [this regexstorm.net page](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%22series%22%5cs*%3a%5cs*%5c%5b%5c%7b%5cs*%22name%22%5cs*%3a%5cs*%22%5b%5e%22%5d%2b%22%2c%5cs*%22data%22%3a%5cs*%5c%5b%29%2c&i=%3c!DOCTYPE+html%3e%0d%0a+%3chtml%3e%3cbody%3e%3cdiv+class%3d%22main-section%22%3e%3c%2fdiv%3e%3cscript%3evar+options+%3d+%7b%0d%0a%22chart%22%3a%7b%0d%0a%22id%22%3a%22ChartID-qn5g8ay9%22%2c%0d%0a%22height%22%3a%22350px%22%2c%0d%0a%22type%22%3a%22bar%22%2c%0d%0a%22stacked%22%3atrue%7d%2c%0d%0a%22title%22%3a%7b%0d%0a%22text%22%3a%22Fictional+Books+Sales%22%7d%2c%0d%0a%22legend%22%3a%7b%0d%0a%22show%22%3atrue%2c%0d%0a%22position%22%3a%22top%22%7d%2c%0d%0a%22plotOptions%22%3a%7b%0d%0a%22bar%22%3a%7b%0d%0a%22horizontal%22%3atrue%7d%7d%2c%0d%0a%22dataLabels%22%3a%7b%0d%0a%22enabled%22%3atrue%2c%0d%0a%22offsetX%22%3a-6%2c%0d%0a%22style%22%3a%7b%0d%0a%22fontSize%22%3a%2212px%22%7d%7d%2c%0d%0a%22series%22%3a%5b%7b%0d%0a%22name%22%3a%22Tank+Picture%22%2c%0d%0a%22data%22%3a%5b%2c%2c%2c%2c%2c%2c%5d%7d%2c%7b%0d%0a%22name%22%3a%22Bucket+Slope%22%2c%0d%0a%22data%22%3a%5b53%2c32%2c33%2c52%2c13%2c43%2c32%5d%7d%5d%2c%0d%0a%22xaxis%22%3a%7b%0d%0a%22categories%22%3a%5b%222008%22%2c%222009%22%2c%222010%22%2c%222011%22%2c%222012%22%2c%222013%22%2c%222014%22%5d%7d%7d%0d%0avar+chart+%3d+new+ApexCharts%28document.querySelector%28%27%23ChartID-qn5g8ay9%27%29%2c%0d%0a++++++++++++options%0d%0a++++++++%29%3b%0d%0achart.render%28%29%3b&r=0%2c&o=i).

Comment: legend.  I've been trying to figure this out since about 10% of the time no answer ever comes.

Comment: So if I wanted to evaluate `"","","","","",""` instead of `, , , , ,` , is this a simple change?

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @n8. Note that the regex only matches the _first_ `,` inside `[...]`, so substituting `"",` for `,` at the end of the regex should do. Also see the regexstorm.net link I've added, which allows you to experiment interactively. (Generally, regex101.com is feature-richer, notably including an _explanation_ of the regex, but it doesn't support the .NET regex engine; the Java engine you can select there comes close, but didn't work in this case, due to lack of support of variable-width look-behinds).

Comment: One slight wrinkle: I'm getting the case where this is occurring: `"series":[{
"name":"Data Point 1",
"data":[3,,2,]},{
"name":"Data Point 2",
"data":[0,,,]}`, but I only want the data array for Data Point 1 to be found in any given Series.  Can it be done?  To be clear, the original data values for Data Point 2 are `[,,,]` and I would like for them to remain that way.

Comment: @n8, you can replace `,` at the end of the regex with `\d+,` to match an existing number right after `[` - if you need further help, I suggest asking a _new_, focused question.